# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC - Model doesn't binds

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

Making a few test with Core 6 - MVC.
Can't figure out why while this works:

```
   [HttpPost]
   public IActionResult Create(IFormCollection collection)
```

but when i used the view model, for some reason, doesn't bind to it.

```
   [HttpPost]
   public IActionResult Create(AirplaneViewModel viewmodel)
```

Can't figure why the properties are not set to viewmodel.
The Create View was done using scafolding against this same view model.
any help ?

Comment: Can you share the view code too?

Comment: does the properties name of the `viewmodel` correspond to the view?

Comment: Please show the name attribute of the fileupload input tag